# プログラムが組めない

Tags: python, python3

最終目的：プログラムが組みたい

上の画像のような結果を得るにはどうプログラム組むと良いのでしょうか。

現在の状態：Anacondaをインストールしたが、その先のプログラムの組み方・実行のさせ方が全く分からない。

Comment: 残念ながら現状の質問文だけでは「何が分かっていて、何が分からないのか」が第三者が読み取れません。 / 「アルゴリズムが分からない」「アルゴリズムは分かるが Python でどう書くか分からない」「そもそも Python でプログラムをどう書くか分からない」etc... / "[より詳細に、または明確にする必要がある](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)" と思います。

Comment: 編集してもう少し詳しくしました。以上でも難しいでしょうか。

Comment: タイトルに「Windowsで」とありますが、Windows特有の話題なのでしょうか？ OSにあまり依存しない話題のように見受けられました。

Comment: Windows特有なのかも分かっていません。。
聞きたいことがだんだん絞れてきたのでさらに質問を変えました！

Comment: Paizaの[ヘルプ](https://paiza.io/help)は確認しましたか？おそらくこれはプログラムの問題ではなくて使い方の問題になりそうです。質問の前に一旦落ち着いてヘルプを参照しましょう。「paiza.IOの基本的な使い方」を学んでみてください

Comment: 言語選択がPHPになっていたのが一つ問題だったみたいです！
Python３にして起動したら質問文のようなエラーが出ました(´;ω;｀)

Comment: ここは一問一答のQAサイトです。解決して新しい問題が出るたびに質問を更新することは残念ながらこのサイトの使い方にはあっていません。問題が解決した場合は自己回答をして新しい質問を作ってください

Comment: アドバイスですが参考サイトはpaizaでやることを想定してないさそうです。そもそもほとんど知識がない人間が環境を変えて実行することはかなりハードルが高いです。まずはサイト通りに作るか、もっと本や書籍もしくはオンラインの講習など一から体系的に学べるようなものを参考になさってください。

Comment: すみません。次から新しい質問で投稿するようにします。

Answer (score 1):

言語選択がPHPになっていたのが一つ問題だったみたいです！ Python３に直したら起動することは出来ました！